# IndoorAtlasWayfinding Pod installation error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

When running/installing my pod file

```
use_frameworks!
target 'IndoorNav' do
 source 'git@github.com:IndoorAtlas/CocoaPods-Specs.git'
 pod 'IndoorAtlas', '2.8.1'
 pod 'IndoorAtlasWayfinding', '2.8.0'
end
```

I get the following error

```
Analyzing dependencies
Cloning spec repo `indooratlas` from `git@github.com:IndoorAtlas/CocoaPods-Specs.git`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `git@github.com:IndoorAtlas/CocoaPods-Specs.git` named `indooratlas`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

I also have tried many solutions discussed on https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4293 but couldn't find an answer. Can anyone please help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the podfile should be:

```sh
use_frameworks!
target 'IndoorNav' do
 source 'https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/CocoaPods-Specs.git'
 pod 'IndoorAtlas', '2.8.1'
 pod 'IndoorAtlasWayfinding', '2.8.0'
end
```